# CollapsingToolbarLayout without shadow in expanded state

Tags: android, shadow, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

CollapsingToolbarLayout from appcompat shows shadow in collapsed state, but when expanded (or expanding in process) shadow disappear

My example code https://github.com/NaikSoftware/CollapsingToolbarWithImageAndTabs/tree/master/app

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ua.naiksoftware.hidetabs.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_plus_tabs"
        app:contentScrim="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap|enterAlways"
        app:titleEnabled="false"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar_wrapper">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/appbar_background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/header_back"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_wrapper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/tab_layout_height">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:tabGravity="fill"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/white" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:tint="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:elevation="@dimen/fab_elevation"
    app:layout_behavior="ua.naiksoftware.hidetabs.FabSlidingBehavior"/>
```

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

**Collapsed**
[image: Collapsed state]

**Expanded**
[image: Expanded state]

Comment: @Sjd Did you find solution ? if not then reply back i will post solution.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I had the same issue and found a solution:

First you have to update to the latest Support Library (I use 24.1.0)

Then apply the stateListAnimator to your AppBarLayout:

example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:stateListAnimator="@drawable/appbar_always_elevated"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

and use this xml as animator:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="8dp"
            android:valueType="floatType"
            android:duration="1"/>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Awesome! It also works with `CollapsingToolbarLayout` which has `ImageView`, Thanks.

Comment: does this support all api version ?

Comment: it works, but floating action button with "layout_anchor" param is getting overlapped by appbarlayout

Comment: @AloDev did you find a solution to the fab problem?

Comment: @HeisenBerg No, I didn't

Comment: @AloDev maybe your FAB is at a lower elevation than "8dp", used in the animator?

Comment: @HeisenBerg make your FAB elevation bigger than 8dp

Comment: I actually was trying to achieve the opposite by removing the shadow for all the states. This answer helped me to do so by changing the value of "android:valueTo" from "8dp" to "0dp", and obviously renaming the drawable file from "@drawable/appbar_always_elevated" to "@drawable/appbar_never_elevated".
Thanks :)

Answer (score 20):

You can find official stateListAnimator for AppBarLayout [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/res/animator-v21/design_appbar_state_list_animator.xml)

**1.** Put this `appbar_elevation.xml` into resources directory named `animator-v21`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:ignore="PrivateResource">
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:propertyName="elevation"
            android:valueTo="@dimen/design_appbar_elevation"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

**2.** On AppBarLayout set `android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_elevation"`

Comment: update for the deadlink: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/res/animator-v21/design_appbar_state_list_animator.xml

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
app:liftOnScroll="false"
```

on the AppBarLayout

Comment: thanks  but I asked 6y ago, there was an old api

Comment: You may have asked the question 6 years ago but I found this answer today.  It's THE most helpful answer.